# cloning element in responsive layout using enquire.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, enquire.js

I'm making a responsive navigation that moves part of a navigation in a different spot between mobile and desktop.

I'm using enquire.js for this to register my breakpoints and move things based on page width.

I am cloning the element and appending it to a different part of the page.

The issue i'm having is that when I go between the mobile and desktop views, the element gets cloned each time - so they start to pile up in desktop view.

I'm not that familiar with enquire.js to make it so that the element only clones if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `element length` before `cloning` like,

```
if( !$('your-element').length ) // if element not exists then clone
{
    // your code to clone the element
}
```

If you provide **some code** to `test` or make a `fiddle` then it will more clear to us **what you tried** and what you need.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. Sorry for the lack of a fiddle or code - i realise that makes it difficult to answer. I was trying to fix a bug before end of day and was in a hurry. I find that sometimes typing out the issue i'm having on here helps me identify what the problem is, or at least i'm descriptive enough so that someone has an idea of what i'm talking about. Your answer hit it exactly on the head!